# Freemarker template do not load

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, freemarker

I am using `Spring` + `Freemarker` as a template to send emails but everytime i try to send a mail I get the message

```
freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "template.ftl".
```

My code is the follow:

```
 // Configuration - AppConfig.java
@Bean
public freemarker.template.Configuration freeMarkerConfigurationFactory() throws Exception{
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory fmcf = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
    fmcf.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/META-INF/freemarker/");          
    fmcf.setPreferFileSystemAccess(false);
    fmcf.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");        
    return fmcf.createConfiguration();
}
```

Mail sender service

```
    @Override
    @Async
    public void sendActivationMail(User user, HttpServletRequest request, String restorePasswordId) throws MailException, MessagingException, GetDataException {                 
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(user.getEmail()));             
        mimeMessage.setSubject(SOFTWARE_NAME + " - Activation");
        mimeMessage.setHeader("content-type", "text/html");    
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("link", ServletUtility.getCompleteAdress(request)+"/auth/confirm/"+restorePasswordId);        
        try{
            mimeMessage.setContent(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(freeMakerConfiguration.getTemplate("template.ftl"), map),
                    "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);        
    }
```

And this is my directory tree:

```
    src
    -main
    --java
    --- it.navium.secutor
    ----AppConfig.java
    --resources
    --webapp
    ---META-INF
    ----freemarker
    -----template.ftl
```

Comment: `src/main/webapp` isn't the classpath... So trying to load from `classpath:META-INF` will not work unless you move the `META-INF` to `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thank you I have solved placing "templates" directory under "src/main/resources" and it Works! :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Spring boot case

If you are using spring boot, the location of the template should be `resources/templates`. Take a look the reference documentation section [Template Engines](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines):

> ....
>
> Spring Boot includes auto-configuration support for the following
> templating engines:
>
> - FreeMarker
> - Groovy
> - Thymeleaf
> - Velocity (deprecated in 1.4)
> - Mustache
>
> .....
>
> When you’re using one of these templating engines with the default > configuration, **your templates will be picked up automatically from >src/main/resources/templates**.

Comment: There is nothing to demonstrate Spring Boot usage to assume that.

Comment: @dimitrisli Why downvote? I've put the answer for spring boot users, maybe it will be helpful for someone, if you read the answer I say "if you are using spring boot". And finally seems he resolves his question with my answer. So, in my opinion your answer would be the correct answer, but this is an alternative for spring boot and it's not a bad answer.

Comment: removing downvote due to author's most recent comment still not clear though whether he was using Spring Boot.

Comment: can you please edit your answer somehow since it's not letting me remove downvote since it was casted more than 3hrs ago "unless edited". So I'm guessing some dummy edit would do it.

Comment: @dimitrisli Edited ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perform the below 3 actions and you should be good to go:

1. Rename your `webapp` directory to `WEB-INF`
2. lose the in-between `META-INF` directory meaning your new tree structure will look like:

> ```
> -WEB-INF
> --freemarker
> ---template.ftl
> ```

3. Change in your FreeMarker Bean definition the classpath string litteral to: `fmcf.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/freemarker/");`